# Making only certain words in line of text bold

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make only the word "Name:" bold in code below, but am unsure as to the best way to do that. I have tried the "textspan" function and putting the two words on seperate lines but this does not seem to be working.

The original code is below:

```
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.book,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            title: Text("Name: Timmy",
            style: theme.textTheme.body1),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) with [TextSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html) like this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle defaultStyle = TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0);
    return RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            style: defaultStyle,
            text: "Name: ",
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: 'Timmy', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
            ],
          ),
        );
  }
```

or like this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle defaultStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0);
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: defaultStyle,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: 'Name: ', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          TextSpan(text: 'Timmy'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]